# How to group by keys of stream of pairs

Tags: java, java-stream

Say that I have the following stream:

```
...
import javafx.util.Pair;
...
Pair[] testPairs = {
        new Pair<>("apple", "James"),
        new Pair<>("banana", "John"),
        new Pair<>("grapes", "Tom"),
        new Pair<>("apple", "Jenkins"),
        new Pair<>("banana", "Edward"),
        new Pair<>("grapes", "Pierre")
};

Map<String, List<String>> result1 = Arrays.stream(testPairs)...;

Map<String, String> result2 = Arrays.stream(testPairs)...;
```

For ***result1***, I want to group by keys of the pairs and get all the correspondant names.
For ***result2***, I want to group by keys and get whichever in the ***list of strings*** (of the previous result). 
How is it possible to achieve that by using java 8 stream api ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may do it like so,

```
Map<String, List<String>> result1 = Arrays.stream(testPairs)
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Pair::getS, 
        Collectors.mapping(Pair::getT, Collectors.toList())));

Map<String, String> result2 = Arrays.stream(testPairs)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Pair::getS, Pair::getT, (v1, v2) -> v1));
```

If you are using row types with arrays, here's the version with the necessary casts as specified by the below comment by YCF_L.

```
Map<String, List<String>> result1 = Arrays.stream(testPairs)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p -> (String) p.getKey(),
                Collectors.mapping(p -> (String) p.getValue(), Collectors.toList())));

Map<String, String> result2 = Arrays.stream(testPairs)
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                        p -> (String) p.getKey(), 
                        p -> (String) p.getValue(), 
                        (a, b) -> b)
                );
    }
```

Comment: Pair is defined like so `Pair<K extends Object, V extends Object>` so the key and the value is an Object, your solution is correct you need just to cast both the key and value

Comment: I've got the following error: cannot resolve method "getS", I think you mean "Pair::getKey", but if I do this, I will get another error: Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context.

Comment: `getS` and `getT` here refers to `getKey` and `getValue` methods respectively. So substitute them with your counterparts which is defined in your `Pair` class.